# if statement in mysql trigger definition

Tags: mysql, triggers

I got an error on the following code.

```
CREATE TRIGGER au_auction AFTER UPDATE ON dmtable 
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.bid > OLD.bid THEN
            INSERT INTO auction_log(auction,id,ts,item,bid) VALUES('update',NEW.id,NEW.ts,NEW.item,NEW.bid);
        END IF;

    END;
```

the problem lies at the syntax level... could you please give more light ?

here is the error Message:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

MySql 5.x

thanks

Comment: you are missing a `;` after the `INSERT`

Comment: added!! but still remain like that

Comment: try setting the delimiter to something else (for example `DELIMITER $$;`) then running the `CREATE TRIGGER` with a `END$$` instead of `END;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER au_auction AFTER UPDATE ON dmtable 
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.bid > OLD.bid THEN
            INSERT INTO auction_log(auction,id,ts,item,bid)
                           VALUES('update', NEW.id, NEW.ts, NEW.item, NEW.bid);
        END IF;

    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Read the [documentation about creating triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html), the examples are helpful.